# Any mature parser generators for both php and javascript on the market?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

Are there known and mature parser generators that both support php and javascript?

The aim is to have a single grammar definition and parsers in php and javascript that are generated from it.

Are there any?

Comment: You mean, one parser for both o0

Comment: @php NoOb: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Here are something for you to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebnf

Comment: If you're looking for a yacc/lex type of deal, someone actually asked that earlier today...

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to write a single grammar definition and get a working parser generated for both languages.

Comment: @Dagg Nabbit: yep, it would be nice. PS: there is a link in the Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79584/are-there-any-parsing-expression-grammar-peg-libraries-for-javascript-or-php?rq=1 but `php-peg` unfortunately is died (and with weird not fixed bugs)

Comment: @zerkms unfortunately, questions about lexers don't seem very well-received here, but you're probably got a big enough number next to your name to counteract those negative effects ;)

Comment: @Dagg Nabbit Why not? :( Lexers are awesome! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. [Have look at ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets). Note: this is for ANTLR3. There's already a new version (ANTLR4) but it supports only Java and C# at the time being.

Comment: Yep, I've used ANTLR for .NET, but now I need something that supports both `php` and `javascript`

Comment: .. which it does. So what's the problem here?

Comment: oops, I see now. It worth at least checking , though php target project looks inactive. Thanks

Comment: Checked it. And it's a piece of crap. I cannot generate parsers even for a trivial grammatics. So sad :-(